# Run Tomcat from Java Web Start

Tags: java, tomcat, java-web-start

Is it possible to distribute Tomcat by Java Web Start and run it from there?

My application shall run within its own Tomcat server on the machine it is deployed on. Can I package Tomcat and the client application into one Java Web Start archive and run the Tomcat server and the client once the user has 
downloaded the Java Web Start archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run a full blown Tomcat as it expects a certain layout in the filesystem and scripts and more.

You can however run an *embedded* web server in an application where you control it completely.  I have done that with Jetty.  You might find [Howto embed Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640022/howto-embed-tomcat-6) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible if you signed all the jars correctly.  But, it seems like this is quite a heavyweight solution.  Have you considered doing this with [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)?

Comment: What does "sign the jars correctly" mean? Can you give some more detail?