# How to check if Tomcat runnning using Embedded Tomcat

Tags: tomcat6

In reference with one of the articles: [Howto embed Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640022/howto-embed-tomcat-6)

I understood how to embed tomcat in a java application. Thanks for that.
However I need to know if there is any elegant method provided by org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded to check if the container is already started or not?

For example, if I create a batch file for the example given in the link above and click it twice; second time it would fail with JVM_BIND error; tomcat is running.

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the example code given on the Tomcat wiki

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_check_whether_Tomcat_is_UP_or_DOWN.3F_There_is_no_status_command

Note: This doesnt use `Embedded`

It is trying to connect to the Tomcat ip:port and seeing if it responds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It really helped and I was able to check if tomcat is running!

Comment: The question asked abut embedded tomcat. Does not answer the question as posed.