# How to stop tomcat through a Java program?

Tags: java, tomcat6, tomcat

I am starting the embedded tomcat successfully through Java program. But I am unable to stop the tomcat server. How do I stop tomcat through a Java program?.

Answer (score 2):

See: [howto-embed-tomcat-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640022/howto-embed-tomcat-6)

Answer (score 0):

and/or see this as well

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/04/03/tomcat.html

Answer (score 0):

How about a System.exec ("tomcatInstallPath/bin/shutdown.sh")

Just a sugestion, I've never tried it.
I just like quick/fast/direct solutions.