# How to: Java app to start a http server on a separate thread

Tags: java, httpserver

Is there a solution out there that can help on that? basically I want to build a Java app that could start a http server on a separate thread such that a local running app could call to this Java app by making HTTP calls.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a threading issue...you want two `apps` to communicate using HTTP, or two `threads`? could you be more clear?...maybe provide some code?

Comment: exactly, i didn't meant for that. :)

Comment: so this isn't a threading issue?

Comment: mre, sorry but i don't know why you still think it's a threading issue. :) did i tag it as threading issue or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [embed Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty) into your Java app to run an HTTP server. It's also possible with [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) however it's more involved, see [Howto embed Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640022/howto-embed-tomcat-6)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/). It is written in one single Java file, with no external dependencies, and is very easy to [embed](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/HelloServer.java.html).