# Embedded Tomcat not serving static content

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm using the following (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640022/howto-embed-tomcat-6)) to create an embedded Tomcat server:

```
File catalinaHome = new File(".");
File webAppDir = new File("web");

Embedded server = new Embedded();
server.setCatalinaHome(catalinaHome.getAbsolutePath());

Context rootContext = server.createContext("", webAppDir.getAbsolutePath());
rootContext.setParentClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

Host localHost = server.createHost("localhost", webAppDir.getAbsolutePath());
localHost.addChild(rootContext);

Engine engine = server.createEngine();
engine.setName("localEngine");
engine.addChild(localHost);
engine.setDefaultHost(localHost.getName());
server.addEngine(engine);

Connector http = server.createConnector((InetAddress) null, 8080, false);
server.addConnector(http);

server.setAwait(true);
server.start();
```

The web directory has static content (index.html, etc.) as well as a WEB-INF directory with servlet descriptors like web.xml.  This is starting without exception and the servlets defined in web.xml work, but static content like index.html aren't working.

I'm confused: what am I missing to get the static content handled?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to define the [default servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html). It's the one responsible for serving static content. This can be done by either explicitly declaring it in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/web.xml` the same way as Tomcat's own regular `/conf/web.xml` is doing, or in the following declarative manner for embedded Tomcat:

```
// Define DefaultServlet.
Wrapper defaultServlet = rootContext.createWrapper();
defaultServlet.setName("default");
defaultServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
defaultServlet.addInitParameter("debug", "0");
defaultServlet.addInitParameter("listings", "false");
defaultServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
rootContext.addChild(defaultServlet);
rootContext.addServletMapping("/", "default");
```

You'd probably also like to do the same for the [JSP servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) so that you can also use JSPs:

```
// Define JspServlet.
Wrapper jspServlet = rootContext.createWrapper();
jspServlet.setName("jsp");
jspServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet");
jspServlet.addInitParameter("fork", "false");
jspServlet.addInitParameter("xpoweredBy", "false");
jspServlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
rootContext.addChild(jspServlet);
rootContext.addServletMapping("*.jsp", "jsp");
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of configuring the wrappers like [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) showed, you can also use this one-liner which does (*almost*) exactly the same:

```
Tomcat.initWebappDefaults(rootContext);
```

Add this line somewhere before you start your server. Tested with **JDK1.7** and **Tomcat 7.0.50**.

**Note**: It additionally adds *welcome files* and some *MIME Type mappings*. The method looks like following:

```
public static void initWebappDefaults(Context ctx) {
        // Default servlet 
        Wrapper servlet = addServlet(
                ctx, "default", "org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.setOverridable(true);

        // JSP servlet (by class name - to avoid loading all deps)
        servlet = addServlet(
                ctx, "jsp", "org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet");
        servlet.addInitParameter("fork", "false");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(3);
        servlet.setOverridable(true);

        // Servlet mappings
        ctx.addServletMapping("/", "default");
        ctx.addServletMapping("*.jsp", "jsp");
        ctx.addServletMapping("*.jspx", "jsp");

        // Sessions
        ctx.setSessionTimeout(30);

        // MIME mappings
        for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_MIME_MAPPINGS.length;) {
            ctx.addMimeMapping(DEFAULT_MIME_MAPPINGS[i++],
                    DEFAULT_MIME_MAPPINGS[i++]);
        }

        // Welcome files
        ctx.addWelcomeFile("index.html");
        ctx.addWelcomeFile("index.htm");
        ctx.addWelcomeFile("index.jsp");
    }
```