# Configure tomcat runtime using maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, m2e

Is it possible to configure a complete tomcat runtime within Eclipse using Maven/m2eclispe.

A maven goal to downloaded tomcat, create the server withing the eclipse environment and add the specified war files to the server ?

Or can some of these goals be implemented ?

Comment: Good question. I personally use Jetty for local testing. Perhaps you can integrate [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/641028/267197) into your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this solution](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/TYNAMO/Developing+with+Tomcat+and+Eclipse) or check out the [maven cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin).

The first solution uses the sysdeo tomcat plugin, which I've personally used in the past, which worked quite well. It does not download tomcat though for you. You will have to do that manually.

Right now I'm working with the maven cargo plugin (not an eclipse plugin though), which will download a tomcat instance for your for development purposes.