# How to Embed tomcat in java

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to embed tomcat in java application. I searched the google but no luck. i was not able to find good tutorial. is there any complete tutorials or api docs for embedding tomcat.
this question might be duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640022/howto-embed-tomcat-6). but it seems old. I read that tomcat 7 api over tomcat 6 is lot improved. so i considered it as old. Any links for tutorials is appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: any reason you must use tomcat? there are other embedded http servers in java.

Answer (score 14):

there's a more recent tutorial about embedding tomcat 8 [here](http://blog.sortedset.com/embedded-tomcat-jersey/).

the gist of it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(8080);

    //actually deploy stuff on your tomcat by defining contexts          

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

Comment: would you please say something about how to stop the running tomcat?just `tomcat.getServer().stop();`.

Comment: @Ron - looks like you just did :-)

Comment: Here's another good tutorial on how to embed Tomcat, for Tomcat 8. http://www.jofre.de/?p=1227