# Ports 1100, 1101 etc are getting occupied by my server

Tags: java, tomcat

I found out that my server (Java with Embedded Tomcat) is using ports between 1000-1100 sporadically.

Those are not ports that I've set, how can I find what in my server is using them?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `tomcat installation directory`... then search for folder `conf`... in that search for `servers.xml`....

Open that file in any of web browser....And then search for the following lines...

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

<Connector port="8008" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

These are the ports used by your tomcat...

Comment: I'm using embedded tomcat so I don't have files, everything done programmatically. I also know that I've not set any of these ports.

Comment: See this it might help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640022/howto-embed-tomcat-6 there you can change the tomcat ports manually

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. I'm setting my http and https ports, and I now what they are. Plus, I'm talking ~10 open ports simultaneously.

Comment: Can you start your tomcat in debug mode.... As i haven't used embedded tomcat yet so i am asking for it